# Como inserir sequência em campo não auto-incrementado

Tags: sql, postgresql

Preciso inserir registros numa tabela com dados de outra continuando a sequência de uma coluna que já existe nela, porém a coluna que quero continuar a sequência não é auto-incrementada e a tabela não possui chave primária.

Situação:

Tabela **fornecedores**:

```
cod | nome
--------------------
3   | Aloha
12  | Castor
21  | Tesla
```

Tabela **contatos**:

```
cod | nome
--------------------
1   | Canada
2   | Asteca
3   | Limiar
```

Gostaria de poder fazer um insert mais ou menos assim na tabela **contatos**:

```
INSERT INTO contatos (cod, nome)
SELECT (SELECT MAX(cod) FROM contatos)+1, nome FROM fornecedores;
```

Esperando esse resultado:

```
cod | nome
--------------------
1   | Canada
2   | Asteca
3   | Limiar
4   | Aloha
5   | Castor
6   | Tesla
```

Porém o resultado está sendo esse (repetindo o código):

```
cod | nome
--------------------
1   | Canada
2   | Asteca
3   | Limiar
4   | Aloha
4   | Castor
4   | Tesla
```

Como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
INSERT INTO contatos (cod, nome)
SELECT 
    (coalesce((SELECT 
         MAX(cod) 
     FROM contatos),0)+ row_number() OVER ()), nome FROM fornecedores;
```

Coloquei o coalesce, para se caso a tabela `contatos` estiver vazia, não dê problemas, e utilizei o `row_number` como incremento. Utilizar o +1 Como incremento só irá funcionar em um `insert`, pois o valor de `Max(cod)` vai ser o mesmo em todas as linhas retornadas pelo `select` por isso o valor retornado fica repetido.

Coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/45bc5/4

Comment: Era exatamente isso que estava precisando, muito obrigado!

Comment: Olá Rovann, como vai? Sei que você é especialista em Postgres então vou te fazer uma pergunta, é possível que o Postgres salve um arquivo.txt através de uma trigger? Por exemplo: após um insert ele salva a informação de uma coluna no txt.

Comment: Eu fiz pesquisas e não encontrei nada...

Comment: Obrigado mas esse título de especialista não me cabe =/ rsrs Para salvar algum dado em um arquivo txt, só utilizar o `copy` exemplo: `copy (select 'teste' ) to 'D:/Teste/teste.txt'`onde `D:` é uma unidade do servidor (windows). Basta colocar esse comando na sua trigger... documentação: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-copy.html

Comment: Nossa, ajudou muito. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se puder garantir que a tabela de fornecedores tem código sequencial começando em 1 pode fazer:

```
INSERT INTO contatos (cod, nome)
SELECT (SELECT MAX(cod) FROM contatos) + cod, nome FROM fornecedores;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Sequence.sql).

Se não puder fazer isto então precisaria ver os critérios para achar uma solução adequada.

Claro que eu não descartaria transformar `cod` de `contatos` em uma coluna serial, mesmo que só para fazer esta operação.

Tem como fazer uma *procedure* ou um código em outra linguagem que faça coluna por coluna. Seria um código simples demais, só criar uma variável e incrementá-la.

Se eu pensar em mais alguma coisa eu posto aqui. É possível que tenha algum truque com `SELECT` simples e puro que dê para ir incrementando na mão. Eu sei que dá para fazer um `JOIN`, mas acho muito complicado e *gambi* demais.

Comment: Obrigado pela Ideia Maniero, mas a resposta do [Rovann Linhalis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69359/rovann-linhalis) serviu perfeitamente! Não dá problema nas situações que na tabela fornecedores os códigos estão com sequência faltando e também não iniciam com 1.

Comment: Sim, concordo..